# Cant access variable that was initialized in try/catch statment

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, try-catch

I am making a sound class for my game and after trying and trying i cant seem to get rid of the NullPointerException. This is happening because I cant access a variable in a try/catch statement.

Here is the code:

```
package util;

import java.applet.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Sound 
{
    private AudioClip audio;
    private URL file;

    public Sound(String srcfile)
    {
        try 
        {
            this.file = new URL(srcfile);
        } 
        catch(Exception e){}

        this.audio = Applet.newAudioClip(file);
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        this.audio.play();
    }

    public void Loop()
    {
        this.audio.loop();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.audio.stop();
    }

    public AudioClip getAudio() 
    {
        return audio;
    }

    public void setAudio(AudioClip audio) 
    {
        this.audio = audio;
    }
}
```

Here is the error(no longer getting):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.applet.AppletAudioClip.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(Unknown Source)
    at util.Sound.<init>(Sound.java:19)
    at main.Blocks.run(Blocks.java:38)
    at main.Blocks.main(Blocks.java:26)
```

After revising the old code her is the new code:

```
package util;

import java.applet.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class Sound 
{
    private AudioClip audio;

    public Sound(String srcfile)
    {
        try 
        {
            this.audio = Applet.newAudioClip(new URL("file://" + srcfile));
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.log(e.getMessage(), Log.ERROR);
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        this.audio.play();
    }

    public void Loop()
    {
        this.audio.loop();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.audio.stop();
    }

    public AudioClip getAudio() 
    {
        return audio;
    }

    public void setAudio(AudioClip audio) 
    {
        this.audio = audio;
    }
}
```

I am calling
    Play();
but nothings happening

Here is how I'm calling the method:

```
Sound snd = new Sound("res/dev/sound.wav");
snd.Play();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Never do this `catch(Exception e){}`. Log it at least.

Comment: Why don't just put `this.audio = Applet.newAudioClip(file);` inside the `try`.

Comment: `catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: *"This is happening because I cant access a variable in a try/catch statement."* It is actually undoubtedly happening because `new URL(srcfile)` is throwing an exception which your code is eating. Print the stack trace like others are suggesting and then we can help with the actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like from the way your class is designed that there's any need for the `file` variable to exist outside the constructor. Something like this would probably serve well:

```
public Sound(String srcfile) {
        try {
            this.audio = Applet.newAudioClip(new URL(srcfile));
        } 
        catch(Exception e){
             //at least print the stack trace
             e.printStackTrace();
             //do some proper exception handling that makes sense for you app!
        }
}
```